# validate file on the basis of set of records

Tags: java, regex

I'm having a file with multiple set of records.

Multiple set of records in example looks like this

```
X---Header
K
L
M
Z---Footer
X---Header
K
L
M
Z---Footer
```

K, L and M are info records.

When I was having only set of instruction in a file I was validating them like this

First reading the number of records then validate them one by one.

```
if recordsno = 1

   input.record.match(^[X].*$)

else if recordno = 2

   input.record.match(^[Z].*$)

else

   input.record.match(^[K|L|M].*$)
```

If any record doesnt match I was rejecting that record. It was working fine with single set of instruction. I'm performing this activity in etl using java.

But now I'm expecting multiple set of instructions. So in this case how can validate this. Any suggestion please so that I could add more code into my existing to validate this kind of multiple set of instruction.

Mandatory thing is..Header should be start from X, footer with Z and in between records with K or L Or M only.So if there is any record which doesn't match with this format am rejecting the file.

Any suggestions please?

Thanks

Comment: What is `recordsno`?

Comment: Its a record count. Like first record, second record and so on

Comment: Can a record be empty? Can `K` or `L` or `M` repeat or should they only appear once? Can they come in any order?

Comment: They can repeated. That's not a problem but that should start from only K or L or M..if other than that I'm rejecting the whole file basis on incorrect records

Comment: Ok, if you can validate the whole file contents, you might use [`\AX.*(?:\r?\n[KLM].*)*\r?\nZ.*(?:\r?\nX.*(?:\r?\n[KLM].*)*\r?\nZ.*)*\z`](https://regex101.com/r/fUUHJj/2) regex. I am not sure if this will work in ETL.

Comment: can you explain me little bit what its doing ..your regex ?

Comment: From the start of the string, match a line starting with `X`, then match 0 or more lines starting with `K`, `L`, or `M`, then match a line starting with `Z`, and repeat this pattern zero or more times up to the string end.

Comment: So do you think so that can work for multiple set of instructions..not for only two like I have mentioned in example ?

Comment: It would work with 1 or more instruction sets.

Comment: Can you help me to run on regex portal to see how it works ?

Comment: I have already provided a link above, it is https://regex101.com/r/fUUHJj/2

Comment: Hey @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for your this kind help. But when I'm running this regex its gives a valid output if there is only single set of records but when I aplly for multiple set of records it doesnt work. Whether its valid set or not valid. In multiple its not working. Could you please check the attached screen shot. http://prnt.sc/dc3q28

Comment: If you are passing the input on a per row basis, it should not work. It will work on the whole input.

Comment: Ah okay..normally input_row.content is object . And context.regex is manually created variable. I can create it as object as well. SO but when I use context.regex (object type) to match regex..its shows error. Please check the attached screen shot. http://prnt.sc/dc468l  Any way to cast matches for objects ?

Comment: No, it is not correct. You cannot run a regex on a regex in this case.

Comment: So how can make it work in my code..any suggestion ?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Okay I will try to use this regex in some other way. But Is one thing possible that I could check the length of every record as well in same regex. Lets say every record should be having 10 characters. Where I can add this character limit into this regex for every record ?

Comment: All I can share is a hint that you should not rely on sole regex when you have so many requirements.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the general requirements you have set out in your question, I believe that you should use one of the mentioned Java libraries on this website [JsaPar - library links](https://org-tigris-jsapar.github.io/jsapar/links) instead of trying to solve this using regular expressions.

There are some truly excellent Java libraries that will do what you have in mind.

This is probably not a direct answer to your question, but that is because the question is (for me, that is) too broad in what actually needs to be solved/accomplished.

Just have a look at the documentation of BeanIO, FlatWorm, JsaPar, EasyBatch, JFFP, etc.

In order to get more reactions (or better reactions) to your question, try to describe in detail what the records contain and how to detect them (what makes them unique to work with?). You can improve your question by specifying how you want to (or must, based on requirements) solve the problem: is an external library allowed to be used? Is it mandatory to use regex only? Are there any speed/memory usage requirements, etcetera.

I think the answer given by user Wiktor Stribiżew is correct: "All I can share is a hint that you should not rely on sole regex when you have so many requirements.". I can only acknowledge that.

Good luck!

Comment: Next time, try clarifying the question first using comments before posting an answer.

Comment: The answer contains a solution direction and some advise to the topic starter. The question is too broad to be answered directly as a working solution, as already concluded by user Wiktor Stribiżew. I believe it's better to provide some pointers to documentation in which the TS can find detailed solutions that could solve or clarify the problem the TS wants to solve. There is nothing wrong with that IMHO.

Comment: You are right. What I meant is that if the question is too broad it is better to get the asker to narrower the scope so that you can provide a cleaner answer. Otherwise you risk missing the mark entirely by answering the wrong question.  Just helpful advice to a new user.

Comment: That is true, but I can always edit my answer when the TS has narrowed his/her answer. But before the TS can do this, I can provide an answer that points him/her in a direction to solve it with another approach that the TS didn't think of in the first place. Adjusting the question and the answer(s) is maybe even better in this case. Thanks for the advise.